# Puppeteer behavior with a windows user session locked

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using often Puppeteer through my projects and I'm pretty familiar with it. Today I suspected a strange behavior from Puppeteer and I would know if that is "normal" or something linked with my code.

I'm using 3 instances of the chromium to perform multiple parallel tasks.

The **Main** program doing the following steps:

1. Every x time start a "RUN" function x3 (3 instances)
2. Lock the "lock" to avoid to run again 3 new instances
3. `Promise.all([Run(1), Run(2), Run(3)]`
4. When all is finished release the "lock", ready to perform the next task

Inside a **Run** task there is:

1. Start browser
2. `page.goto`
3. `page.evaluate`
4. Manage the data returns by the step above
5. Close browser

But randomly the step 3 promise (`page.evaluate`) do not resolve, like never. This freezes the entire solution (because `Promise.all` keeps waiting).

I'm currently investigating the code passed as parameter to `page.evaluate`, thinking that it's maybe because of an infinite loop, but honestly, I start to doubt it.

I figure out that this happens often when the user lock is windows session or sign out of the windows session.

Could this make any sense and be linked?

**Edit:** I tryed to add a `page.screenshot` just before my `page.evaluate` and now the `page.screeshot` do not resolve...